# PowerShell script to automatically adjust system date/time

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-11, date-time

I'm looking for something very specific. I've been searching it for weeks on and off whenever I have the time and now I just few like I'm wasting time because I can't find anything, so I guess the last option is to just ask *somebody*, and I don't even know if the thing that I'm looking for is even possible.

So here we go. I have a few *old* games and programs that won't even launch unless I set the system date/time to a couple of years back.

My goal is to automate the process so, normally, using a program called *RunAsDate* would take care of the issue. And it does in some cases, however when I launch *games* using RunAsDate, for whatever reason, it changes the game to windowed mode and sets the resolution to 320p or something and I can't change it in-game, It simply doesn't recognize other resolutions. I searched and I searched but couldn't any solution to this new issue.

So, I started to look for other options and I ended up founding a very, very *basic* PowerShell script to sets the date/time to whatever value I desire. It's very useful because I use a program called Playnite to organize my games, and it lets you set PowerShell scripts to run before running a game, during it, and after you close it. It's pretty cool, so I just put the script I found (**set-date -date "DD/MM/YYYY 00:00"**) to run before the game opens and it does the job so now I only have to press "play" to actually play the game. That's great, but! I still have to go to the system settings and manually change the time back to the correct date after I close the game.

I would like to know if there's a PowerShell script to automatically change the date/time to the correct values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We do not write PowerShell scripts based on a requirement, We can help you write that script, but you must make a valid and honest attempt at writing the script. We can help you get over the finish line, but we will NOT run the entire race for you. You likely will have to perform a CURL request on a website that gives the current time, any method that gets the system time, wouldn't result in the correct result.

Comment: So is there a script to just enable/disable the option "set time automatically" in the settings then?

Comment: I commend to your attention the [`Get-NTPTime` function](https://scripts.lukeleigh.com/_posts/functions/Get-Ntptime/), which appears to be _part_ of what you need.

Comment: The date-time should be automatic in Windows. Have you disabled "Set the time automatically" in *Settings > Time & Language > Date & time*?

Comment: @harrymc Hello mate. I haven't, but that's the issue even though I leave it on all the time, it won't go back to the correct date/time unless I turn this option off and then on again

Comment: Try the fixes in [this article](https://www.wintips.org/fix-windows-10-not-syncing-time-solved/) and report back. Are all the settings that the article advises already this way?

Comment: @harrymc The article helped me a lot. Restarting the service fixed the issue. I tested using a powershell script to restart services and It works, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster's problem was that the Windows Time service was not running.

The solution was to ensure that the service is enabled in the Services applet
and to restart the service.

For more information and advice see the article
[FIX: Windows 10 Not Syncing Time](https://www.wintips.org/fix-windows-10-not-syncing-time-solved/).